# Switch-case does not fire on change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to make dynamic slider which changes background color depending on which value it has been slided to. I am doing this with a simple `switch-case`, but it does not seem to enter this statement.

The implementation can also be found on: http://jsfiddle.net/3pLUX/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var change_var = $('#slider_pain').val();
    $('#slider_pain').bind('change', function () {
        if (change_var !== $(this).val()) {
            change_var = $('#slider_pain').val();
            console.log(change_var);
            switch(change_var) {
                case 1:
                    break;
                case 2: 
                    console.log("#2");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    break;
                case 4:
                    break;
                case 5:
                    break;
                case 6:
                    break;
                case 7:
                    break;
                case 8:
                    break;
                case 9:
                    break;
                case 10:
                    break;
                default:
            }
    }});
});
```

Comment: change  switch(change_var) to switch(+change_var); or to avoid the conversion to a number, you can change the cases and make them strings e.g. '1', '2'. The issue is that JavaScript will not use implicit coercion when values are used in a switch/case. It will do that when for example it needs to evaluate an expression into a boolean value e.g. 1 == '1' (but not 1 === '1')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`change_var` holds a string value. and your `case` statements look for numeric matches.

Use `switch(parseInt(change_var, 10)) {` instead.

```
switch(parseInt(change_var, 10)) {
case 1: break;
...
}
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3pLUX/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var change_var = $('#slider_pain').val();
    $('#slider_pain').bind('change', function () {
        if (change_var !== $(this).val()) {
            change_var = $('#slider_pain').val();
            console.log(change_var);
            switch(change_var) {
                case '1':
                    break;
                case '2': 
                    console.log("#2");
                    break;
                case '3':
                    break;
                case '4':
                    break;
                case '5':
                    break;
                case '6':
                    break;
                case '7':
                    break;
                case '8':
                    break;
                case '9':
                    break;
                case '10':
                    break;
                default:
            }
    }});
});
```

change_var is string

Answer (score 0):

The type of parameters in switch condition and subsequent cases should be same and in your case they are different. Kindly use below one.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var change_var = $('#slider_pain').val();
    $('#slider_pain').bind('change', function () {
        if (change_var !== $(this).val()) {
            change_var = $('#slider_pain').val();
            console.log(change_var);
            switch(parseInt(change_var)) {
                case 1:
                    break;
                case 2: 
                    console.log("#2");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    break;
                case 4:
                    break;
                case 5:
                    break;
                case 6:
                    break;
                case 7:
                    break;
                case 8:
                    break;
                case 9:
                    break;
                case 10:
                    break;
                default:
            }
    }});
});
```